# Setting up Debian file server, looking for advice about what file system to use

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, zfs, file-server

I'm currently working on setting up a Debian media and torrent server for my home. Most of my home network is comprised of Macs, and up until now my "server" was two 4 TB hard drives formatted HFS+ and plugged into an Airport Extreme, which shared them over the network. One drive was set up as a mirror of the other, updated daily.

It hasn't worked out so well, especially when I try to download a file via BitTorrent on to a remote file system. Turns out the Airport Extreme isn't really up to the job. It's especially bad when torrenting and streaming 1080p video at the same time.

So I'd like to replace it with a Debian server, and continue using both external drives in a mirrored configuration. The question is, what filesystem should I use for these drives, and how should I convert them?

Ideally I'd like the drives to be readable somehow in OS X in case I ever need to access them from one of my Macs. Also, I don't have an extra 4 TB of space floating around anywhere, so I'll have to convert the drives to something usable in Linux one at a time. Since Linux has limited supported for HFS+, I figured I'd mount the existing HFS+ partition on one of the drives read-only, then set up the other one with the filesystem I want to use and copy over the data, then convert the other and copy the data again.

I was thinking ZFS, since it seems to have great performance and reliability, and can be used in both Linux and OS X. Even better if I can use zpools to achieve mirroring, both for the automatic redundancy and possible performance boost. However I haven't really used ZFS before, in Debian or otherwise, so I don't know if there's any snafus I might not be aware of.

Ext4 is another option, since it's certainly tried-and-true in Linux and I think that's readable in OS X, but once again I'm not sure.

I'm certainly open to suggestions, too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the fact that you have hfs+ on the drives now, I would be inclined to leave well enough alone unless there are other issues like incompatible mirror formats, or other performance issues. If you are going to change file systems I believe that ext4 is currently the best general purpose filesystem. I think that your migration strategy sounds fine and has been used before. for cook books search for 'converting raid degraded array'

Comment: The main issue with HFS+ in Linux is that, as far as I know journaling isn't supported. I wouldn't want to host a whole lot of files on an unjournaled file system, if for no other reason than when something goes wrong both 4 TB filesystems will have to be checked for errors -- that'll take a little while. But I also get the impression that it's not necessarily as stable as ext4 either.

Comment: @GuyGizmo both points are true, but you have to weigh those risks against the risks and hassles of migration.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend XFS as a very robust journaled filesystem for video and file storage.  It scales very well, very mature, has very good recovery tools in case of bad things, and is included with debian out of the box.  I use it at our company for large image volumes and it works very well with hundreds of deployed servers over the last fifteen years.

There is also a lot of good research and deployments on ZFS which I'm just experimenting with, so that would also be a good option.

Your not going to find a good filesystem that work for both Mac and Linux at this point...  NTFS is about the only filesystem that is supported for Read/Write on both OSes (Mac needs a third-party paid plugin for write support), though the performance and long-term stability won't be there.  I would suggest picking a good filesystem for your server and leaving the drives there. Besides, if you want to use the filesystem over the network NetATalk is a great linux package for the Apple Filer protocol (AFS) and handles resource forks well, but not direct attached.

Best of luck!